# is data with individual and #event sequence (not fixed time) considered as a panel data?

Tags: panel-data

I have a dataset that includes individual events across a time period. some example records as below, each individual has 2-4 records observed within a period. The event# is ordered by time, however, the same event# did not occur at the same date (A's #1 event occurs on 6/1, while C's #1 event happens on 6/3). Should I analyze the data as an unbalanced panel data with 2 dimensions individual and event #(i.e, the time dimension)? thanks. If not, how should I treat this data? thanks.

| obs | ind | event# | date | var1 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 6/1 | 11 | 33 |
| 2 | A | 2 | 6/4 | 12 | 23 |
| 3 | A | 3 | 6/5 | 13 | 32 |
| 4 | A | 4 | 6/5 | 14 | 55 |
| 5 | B | 1 | 6/1 | 15 | 44 |
| 6 | B | 2 | 6/2 | 18 | 54 |
| 7 | C | 1 | 6/3 | 15 | 22 |
| 8 | C | 2 | 6/3 | 29 | 55 |
| 9 | C | 3 | 6/6 | 31 | 23 |
| 10 | D | 1 | 6/3 | 13 | 45 |
| 11 | D | 2 | 6/5 | 2 | 12 |